# Snapping point to polygon edge nearest weighted feature in different layer using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am trying reproduce the process shown in parts 2 & 3 of the image below. I want to take the centroid of a polygon and snap it to one meter OUTSIDE the edge of the polygon nearest to a weighted feature.

I thought I might be able to do this process using the 'Snap' geoprocessing tool in ArcGIS Pro, but that doesn't produce the desired result.

[image]

I have attempted this on a test dataset using the Snap Geoprocessing tool in ArcGIS Pro by:

1. Generate poygon centroids
2. Snap Geoprocessing tool with the following inputs:

[image]

where `poly_FeaturetoPoint` is my polygon centroids, and `poly` and `lines` are my two feature classes. the distance metrics are less than the distance for any point to touch anywhere on the nearest line.

[image]

Comment: I suspect there are several solutions to this problem I would look at intersecting a line from centroid to weighted edge with a 1m buffer around polygon.